# Which algorithms is enable to solve Tower Of Hanoi with 10 Disk

Tags: python, algorithm, towers-of-hanoi

I've tried to use BFS to solve Tower of Hanoi (with smallest step) with 10 disks and you can put the disk wherever you want but it takes way too long and take so much memory. Do you guys have any suggestion?

Which algorithms should i use for this 10 disks cases and the disk are randomly initiated and you can put the disk wherever you want in the solving process?

My code:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,matrix,parent):
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.parent = parent
        

def CreateNode(matrix,parent) -> Node: 
    new_mat = [nested[:] for nested  in matrix]
    newnode = Node(matrix,parent)
    return newnode

def appender(matrix,i,query,gone,solution):
    if matrix[i] != []:
        for j in range(3):
            if j != i:
                temp = [nested[:] for nested in matrix]
                temp[j].append(temp[i].pop(-1))
                if ''.join(map(str,temp)) not in gone:
                    gone.add(''.join(map(str,temp)))
                    sub_solution = CreateNode(temp,solution)
                    query.append(sub_solution)



def printMatrix(mat):
    for i in mat:
        for j in i:
            print(j,end=" ")
        print()
    print("#")

def PrintSolution(root):
    if root == None:
        return
     
    PrintSolution(root.parent)
    printMatrix(root.matrix)

def solver(A,list):
    
    gone = set()
    query = []
    root = Node(A,None)
    query.append(root)
    
    while query:
        solution = query.pop(0)
        if solution.matrix[-1] == list:
            PrintSolution(solution)
            return
        for i in range(3):
            appender(solution.matrix,i,query,gone,solution)



A = []

for i in range(3):
    arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    A.append(arr)


maxi = max(max(A))

list = []

for i in range(maxi,-1,-1):
    list.append(i)

solver(A,list)
```

Example input :

```
6 9 0 1 2
4 7
3 5 8
```

Output:

```
6 9 0 1 2
4 7
3 5 8
#
6 9 0 1 2
4 7 8
3 5
#
6 9 0 1
4 7 8
3 5 2
#
etc until solved
```

Comment: "Tower of Hanoi" where you can pit a larger disk on top of a smaller one? Please invent a different name for this game, it confuses the audience.

Comment: Where you can put the larger disk on top of smaller one "in the solving process" im sorry.

Comment: I guess how to prove "with smallest step" is the most difficult point? Just stacks 10 plates in order to one tower is trival, if put larger disk onto a smaller one is not banned.

Comment: @ajz34 the trivial solution is not necessarily the shortest one.

Comment: You have to take care that you can not choose from all three poles at any time. At each turn, there are only two poles from which you can take the disc (because 1 was just added) and two poles to which it can be moved. If you allow all 3, you may run into an endless loop and inevitable memory overflow. I'd give it a shot with a recursive function that explores all possible turns.

Comment: the condition j != i (in the appender() function) is to make sure only two poles is allowed

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., ["Tower of Hanoi"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) is clear enough.

Comment: You are not looking for the shortest solution, are you?

Comment: BFS is not a good algorithm for this problem, there are too many nodes and you will eventually need to look at about a half of them. There is a simple algorithm that generates a simple solution. (1) Remove everything from target pin. (2) Do this until solved: (2a) Find largest disk that is still not on target pin (2b) Move everything above that disk to the remaining pin (2c) Move that disk to the target pin.

Comment: If you do look for some kind of optimal solution, then I don't think there is a straightforward solution much better than BFS (unless there is a trick that can significantly cull the search space, but I currently don't see any). You can try a heuristic-based search algorithm such  as A-star but it does not guarantee an optimal solution.

Comment: i think i'm looking for the optimal solution

Answer (score -1):

I think this can quite help with your situation

```
def hanoi(n: int, fromPos: int, toPos: int, via: int) -> None:
    if n == 1:
        print("Move disk from pole %d to pole %d" % (fromPos, toPos)
    else:
        move(n - 1, fromPos, via, toPos)
        move(1, fromPos, toPos, via)
        move(n - 1, via, toPos, fromPos)
```